In which countries can election results be invalidated on the basis of misleading statements made to voters?
In a comment to Have any elections been declared illegitimate despite registering all opposition candidates and fairly counting the votes? @origimbo mentioned the highly peculiar example of (otherwise legitimate) election results declared void by a court in the UK:

After losing the 2010 general election by 103 votes, Liberal Democrat candidate Elwyn Watkins submitted a petition for a hearing by an election court, claiming that campaign literature issued by his Labour opponent Phil Woolas breached the Representation of the People Act 1983 by making false statements about his personal character. On 5 November 2010, the election court upheld the petition and declared the election void after reporting Phil Woolas guilty of making false election statements. Woolas sought a judicial review of the decision in the Administrative Division of the High Court, which upheld the decision of the Election Court in relation to two statements, whilst quashing the decision in relation to a third. As a result, the 2011 Oldham East and Saddleworth by-election was needed.

Are there any other countries where election results can be cancelled solely on the basis of false statements made to voters? This could be misinformation, disinformation, outright lies about opponents, propaganda campaigns by hostile domestic or foreign actors, etc.

We probably need some tag for disqualification or election annulment. If there's something already I couldn't find it.

Interesting case. This is the only example of this being done that I have ever encountered and this almost certainly wouldn't be possible under U.S. law.

@ohwilleke: the UK has the famous "section 106". It doesn't apply to lies in general though. The court has to consider them specifically targeted to change the outcome of the election. There's a bit more about that in this piece when the attempt to overturn an election on such basis failed.

@ohwilleke: also Wales even wants to criminalize it, so you wouldn't just be disqualified thereafter for doing it... https://theconversation.com/wales-could-become-worlds-first-country-to-criminalise-politicians-who-lie-230735

@ohwilleke: however that last piece is wholly incorrect that such [criminal rather than election-annulment] punishments were not attempted elsewhere. Quite a few US states tried them in fact, but they were mostly struck down on free speech basis https://digitalcommons.law.ou.edu/cgi/viewcontent.cgi?article=1345&context=olr

@timetakesitstoll - There are a surprising number of state and city laws in the US that seem like, and probably are, prima facie violations of various constitutional amendments, usually the first, or of civil rights laws and so forth, but which stand because they have not been challenged, often due to lack of application. For instance, laws against "breach of the peace" have frequently been individually struck down as restrictions of freedom of speech, but there are still plenty of city ordinances in this regard that would probably fail a legal challenge but simply have not been contested.
